# Can you help me fix this batch file for file type associations in windows 10?

Tags: batch-file, file-association

I have this batch file in my startup folder.  I do not get any error message.  However, it does not seem to work as the associations are not being mapped as per the batch file.

```
@echo off

ASSOC .html=htmlfile
FTYPE htmlfile="C:\Program Files\Kompozer\kompozer.exe" "%%1"

ASSOC .pdf=acroExch.Document

FTYPE acroExch.Document="C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 11.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" "%%1"
```

Comment: There is no need to repeat the assoc/ftype settings. They should be persistent. What do `ASSOC .html` and `FTYPE htmlfile` return? In windows 10 there are other/newer ways to determine the default application for a file type. See the output of `reg query "hkcr\.html"`

Comment: CMD's `assoc` and `ftype` commands only work on the system file types defined in `HKLM\Software\Classes`. Per-user associations in `HKCU\Software\Classes` take precedence but have to be edited manually in the registry. There are other fallbacks defined in `[HKCU|HKLM]\Software\Classes\Applications` and `[HKCU|HKLM]\Software\Classes\SystemFileAssociations`. Ultimately the primary association is up to the `[extension]\UserChoice` key under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts`. The user choice can be deleted and reset, but not easily edited due to its ACL.

Comment: When Microsoft does a windows update, don't they overwrite registry settings?  If yes, then changing the registry is inefficient as it needs to be done again and again after every windows update.  However, if file and program associations are set by a batch file, they get set correctly every time I boot up, correct?

Comment: That is why I am trying to have a batch file work.  Note also that the associations I am setting ARE defined in HKLM\Software\Classes.  So, can I ask again--can anyone tell me what to fix in the posted batch file to make it work?

Comment: Yes, but `HKCU\Software\Classes` overrides the HKLM setting, and ultimately the `UserChoice` doesn't have to use either. It could be an association defined in `[HKCU|HKLM]\Software\Classes\Applications` or something else entirely. So to begin with, is there a current `UserChoice` for `.html` defined in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\File‌​Exts`?